# How to exclude files in git pre-commit hook with flake8?

Tags: flake8

This is what I have currently:

```
sys.exit(git_hook(complexity=COMPLEXITY, strict=STRICT, ignore='W801,E128,E501,W402,F403'))
```

But it's complaining about django south migration files, so I want to exclude the migration files, my immediate guess was:

```
sys.exit(git_hook(complexity=COMPLEXITY, strict=STRICT, ignore='W801,E128,E501,W402,F403', exclude='migrations'))
```

but getting this error:

```
TypeError: git_hook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exclude'
```

Go through the source code there is no such argument for me to use...

```
def git_hook(complexity=-1, strict=False, ignore=None, lazy=False):
```

Is there a way for me to exclude some files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I have to do is create the configuration file in `~/.config/flake8`:

http://flake8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html

or in project level create `tox.ini`.

Comment: Unfortunately, tox.ini doesn't help on 3.5.0 despite these bug reports marked as fixed: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/issues/218 and user config doesn't allow per-project configuration. Can you verify it with 3.5.0?